# Cannot get output when using Intersect along with a subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, intersect

**Troubles:**

Cannot get an output, meaning definately cannot get correct output.

**Question:**

For this question, the Intersect operator needs to be used. All job types of type 'N' need to be found and having the description as set out in the final line of the code.

Code used:

```
SELECT job_id
FROM bookjobs
WHERE job_id IS 'N'
INTERSECT
SELECT job_id 
FROM po_items
WHERE item_id IS
    (SELECT item_id
    FROM items
    WHERE descr = '9KG PAPER');
```

Expected output:

```
job_id
----------
002
```

Received (from CodeRunner):

No output returned.

---

[See database schema for more details (Primary Keys are in bold).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u42T.png)

Unknown DBMS used. Behaves like `PostgreSQL` and not `mysql`.

Comment: Think that issue with this WHERE job_id IS 'N'. According to your task job type with N should be included. jod_id is never N as it a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother with INTERSECT. Use a join query instead:

```
SELECT bj.job_id
FROM bookjobs bj
INNER JOIN po_items pi ON bj.job_id = pi.job_id
INNER JOIN items i ON pi.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE i.descr = '9KG PAPER';
```

Comment: I know what you mean, thank you for the alternate code, however the question is wanting Intersect. Do you know of a way to do this with using Intersect? 
----
The output given from your code is:
***Runtime error***
Program does not use the expected SET operator or is badly laid out.

Comment: Something like this would work in SQL Server. I'm not sure what your dbms is. `SELECT job_id
FROM bookjobs
INTERSECT
SELECT job_id 
FROM po_items
WHERE item_id in
(SELECT item_id
FROM items
WHERE descr = '9KG PAPER');`

Comment: Thank you Ben, this seems to get close to the right answer. The only difference was 002 and 004 was returned for job_id, instead of the expected output (002) seen in the question.

Comment: Final try: `SELECT job_id FROM bookjobs WHERE jobtype = 'N' INTERSECT SELECT job_id FROM po_items WHERE item_id in (SELECT item_id FROM items WHERE descr = '9KG PAPER');`

Comment: Correct. :-) We are only human. I will be posting another question to my profile in 18 minutes, if you are keen.

Comment: It is actually comparatively similar.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support the `INTERSECT` operator. Use the `UNION` operator, the same rules apply when using the `UNION` operator.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

*Using UNION*

```
(
  SELECT job_id
 FROM bookjobs
 WHERE job_id = 'N'
)
UNION ALL
(
 SELECT job_id
 FROM po_items
 WHERE item_id IN (
   SELECT item_id
   FROM items
   WHERE descr = '9KG PAPER'
 )
);
```

else, you can simply use `INNER JOIN`, it is very easy to use

```
SELECT
  b.job_id
FROM
  bookjobs AS b
  INNER JOIN po_items AS pi ON pi.job_id = b.job_id
  INNER JOIN items AS i ON i.item_id = pi.item_id
WHERE
  b.job_id = 'N'
  AND i.descr = '9KG PAPER'
```

Comment: When replacing with Intersect, output is: ***Runtime error***
Program does not use the expected subquery on the items table or is badly laid out.

Comment: make sure you are using `MySQL` database

Comment: Thank you Anfath, this CodeRunner application behaves like `PostgreSQL` and not `MySQL`. The conventions that Ben Oshman used towards the end worked.